# Any way to create Cache using remotecachemanger on a remote server?

Tags: infinispan

I am trying to setup a replicated cache set up on 2 different servers using Infinispan cache.

Node1 and Node2 are 2 physical servers on which hotrod server is running.

My intention is to create some cache(with custom Configuration) on node1/node2 from a remote client (Node3).

On Node3,
I am trying to do the following..

RemoteCacheManager rm = new RemoteCacheManager ("node1ip4address", portNumber);
rm.getCache("namedcache1"); ----> this method's javadoc says,

/**
    * Retrieves a named cache from the remote server if the cache has been
    * defined, otherwise if the cache name is underfined, it will return null.
*/

I checked the Source code of RemoteCacheManager. This class does not have defineConfiguration() method such as the one exists in EmbeddedCacheManager.

Is there a way i can create cache on remote node?

Thanks,
-Venkat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to create a cache through the HotRod protocol. Even in embedded mode, Infinispan doesn't have a way to say "create this cache on all the cluster nodes", which you would need with HotRod because you don't know which server you're accessing.

The [CacheManager JMX bean](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/jmxComponents.html#CacheManager) has a `startCache` method, but you still can't define new configurations (they'll use the default cache's configuration). And you need to call it on every node of the cluster.

Obviously, it would be best if you could configure the caches statically in the server's configuration.

Comment: Is that expected from infinispan? After some effort, i have short listed to ehcahce with jgroups replication and infinispan.. but infinispan doesn't seem to support my use case of creating cahce from remote client.. Any other cache provider support this usecase? thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's expected for now; can't say anything about other cache providers.

Comment: BTW, I see you've posted the question to the Infinispan forum as well. I'd recommend linking between questions when you cross-post.

Comment: @venkatnaraman : any updates on this? what did you do then? Did you achieve creating named cache from hotrod client? do tell me, I am stuck with this same problem..

Answer (score 2):

We can use the rest call to the management running on 9990 and create the cache,

```
curl --digest -s -i -u "usr:pwd" -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d @cacheTemplate.json http://serverurl:9990/management
```

where the `cacheTemplate.json` to create a cache with name `cart` in the container named `clustered`

```
{
    "address":[
        "subsystem",
        "datagrid-infinispan",
        "cache-container",
        "clustered",
        "configurations",
        "CONFIGURATIONS",
        "distributed-cache-configuration",
        "cart"
    ],
    "operation":"add",
    "mode":"SYNC",
    "store-type":"None",
    "store-original-type":"None",
    "template":false
}
```